# Android imageView with elevation is blocked by text view

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, imageview, android-elevation

I need some help with android layout

Here is a imageView

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_user_profile_avatar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="305dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@color/feed_bg" />
```

And the textView on ImageView

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@+id/user_name"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:fontFamily="roboto-regular"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

It all under one RelativeLayout. When i'm trying to set imageView's elevation, textView is hiding under the imageView.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *android:elevation* on your **TextView** with number higher than that on your **ImageView** i.e as below

```
<ImageView
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_user_profile_avatar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="305dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@color/feed_bg" />

<TextView
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@+id/user_name"
    android:text="Hello This is a TextView"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:fontFamily="roboto-regular"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: Your answer may be better than mine, I've never used elevation before.  I checked out the documentation before following through with my post, and it sounded like it adds shadows, which may or may not be desirable. And that might not always be the case, I don't know.

Comment: okay, but my textview gets and elevation too in this case, and i dont need elevation on textview

Comment: Sorry, my fault. i didnt check it. It works perfectly! Big thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

The relative position in an xml layout is decided by the order in the file.  If you first create the ImageView and then the TextView. It should appear as you want.

```
<RelativeLayout...>

<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/fragment_user_profile_avatar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="305dp"
     android:scaleType="centerCrop"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
     android:background="@color/feed_bg" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@+id/user_name"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:fontFamily="roboto-regular"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: my .xml structure just like you wrote. and still if i add elevation to imageView it hides textview